# Doctrine 2: group by field alias (Error: '...' does not point to a Class. )

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I got this Doctrine query:

```
        select upper(substring(e.name, 1, 1)) first_letter
        from Application\Models\Exercise e
        group by first_letter
        order by first_letter asc
```

But it throws an exception with the message:

```
Error: 'first_letter' does not point to a Class.
```

If I leave out the `group by` and the `order by`, it works.

Do I have to use a native query in this case or do the sorting and grouping in my client code (probably not such a good idea depending on the amount of data in the db...) or is it possible to get this query working?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

This is my current approach, not so nice, but works for the moment as there is not much data in the db:

```
    $tmpResult = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        select upper(substring(e.name, 1, 1)) first_letter
        from Application\Models\Exercise e
    ')->getResult();

    $groupedAndSortedResult = array();

    foreach($tmpResult as $row) {
        $groupedAndSortedResult[$row['first_letter']] = $row['first_letter'];
    }

    sort($groupedAndSortedResult);

    return array_values($groupedAndSortedResult);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you've answered this question yourself but just wondering if you tried using `DISTINCT`:

```
select DISTINCT upper(substring(e.name, 1, 1)) first_letter
from Application\Models\Exercise e    
order by e.name asc
```

Ordering by `e.name` is equivalent to `first_letter` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I´ll give it a try, if this works I´ll apply the checkmark to your answer. :-)

Comment: Yes, this does work! It however returns the array in the form of array(array('first_letter' => 'A'), array('first_letter' => 'B')) but that was not the question. I for myself go with the solution I posted, because array transformation is already done by PDO but I accept your answer as you actually answered my original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no good way to do this via `DQL` (at least none I could find), as Doctrine always tries to map the result to an entity. I ended up doing a native query using the `PDO` connection. Here is the code I use in my repository:

```
    return $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery('
        select upper(left(tl_exercise.name, 1)) as first_letter
        from tl_exercise
        group by first_letter
        order by first_letter asc
    ')->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

At least I got rid of the sorting/grouping in my client code. And I can use the `LEFT()` function which is not available in `DQL` by default (you can use `SUBSTRING()` however).

---

**UPDATE: There is a way** to get this done using `EntityManager::createQuery` and `DQL`, see [**rojoca´s answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995268/doctrine-2-group-by-field-alias-error-does-not-point-to-a-class/4026316#4026316)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is looking for first_letter to be an Entity.  This is similar problem in some sql queries where you can't use a computed attribute from the select statement as criteria.  Try the following:

```
select upper(substring(e.name, 1, 1)) first_letter
from Application\Models\Exercise e
group by upper(substring(e.name, 1, 1))
order by upper(substring(e.name, 1, 1)) asc
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but then I get a SyntaxError Exception.