# Group By aliasin Doctrine. Bug or Feature?

Tags: doctrine-orm, group-by, doctrine, symfony1, alias

I'd like to highlight an issue that was previously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995268/doctrine-2-group-by-field-alias-error-does-not-point-to-a-class), or seems to have been resolved [a long time ago](http://trac.doctrine-project.org/ticket/419), but the problem still persists.

Actually, it's impossible to use an alias in a `group by` clause. 
Like the mentioned topic, I also get an "Error: '...' does not point to a Class". 
However, aliases, in the `order by` clause, work perfectly.

For instance, this DQL request works:

```
SELECT j.id, DATE(j.start_at) AS date
FROM jobs j
ORDER BY date
```

But this doesn't (whereas it works in SQL):

```
SELECT COUNT(j.id), DATE(j.start_at) AS date
FROM jobs j
GROUP BY date
```

Also, I can't `GROUP BY DATE(j.start_at)`.

(I tryed it on a MySQL database, with the version delivered with Symfony PR9, and also the last version in github.com/doctrine/doctrine2 - 04/04/11)

Thus, I'd like to know if this is a bug of Doctrine2, or if it is wanted? In the first case, does somebody know how to correct it?

Comment: Can you not just `GROUP BY j.start_at` it would give the same result.

Comment: No, because in my case, start_at is datetime, so '2011-04-04 10:10:10' and '2011-04-04 11:11:11' won't be grouped together. However, the question is more generally 'Is it normal/Why group by alias is impossible in DQL?'.