# groupBy using alias in Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, group-by

I'm trying to query a database to get all initials from a table. In SQL, the query would be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, 1) AS initial FROM Tool t GROUP BY initial
```

But using QueryBuilder, I haven't found the way to group by aliases. I've tried:

```
 $q = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
     ->select('SUBSTRING(i.name, 1, 1) AS initial')
     ->from('...\Entity\Tool', 't')
     ->groupBy('initial');

Error: 'initial' does not point to a Class.

$q = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
     ->select('SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, 1)')
     ->from('...\Entity\Tool', 't')
     ->groupBy('SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, 1)');

(t.name, 1, ': Error: Cannot group by undefined identification variable.
```

And after half an hour of looking for documentation I'm asking again for help. Is it possible, or should I go to another way ?

Answer (score 2):

Alright,

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995268/doctrine-2-group-by-field-alias-error-does-not-point-to-a-class), the problem comes from my original sql.
Using DISTINCT solve the problem:

```
$q = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('DISTINCT UPPER(SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, 1))')
    ->from('...\Entity\Tool', 't')
    ->orderBy('t.name');
```

An I've added an UPPER for more safety.

Thanks for reading!